# How change the color of an graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, runtime-error, syntax-error

My code:

```
import sympy as smp
from sympy.plotting import plot_parametric

x = smp.symbols('x', real=True)
p=plot( x * smp.sin(x) * smp.exp(-x**2), dfdx, (x, -3, 3),title= "Grafica de la funcion y su derivada en el intervalo [-3,3]", show=False)
p.show()
```

[image: My Graph]

I need change the color of my function and of the derivative

Comment: Your code does not run. Where is `plot` from? Usually there is a `color=` parameter in the plot function, but it depends from which package it is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.